# how to do this without token

Tags: php, facebook, json, facebook-graph-api

**facebook feeds without authentication token**

```
$pageID = "ID of Page"
    $url = "https://graph.facebook.com/". $pageID ."/feed";
    $json = file_get_contents($url);
    $jsonData = json_decode($json);

    foreach($jsonData->data as $val) {
        if($val->from->id == $pageID) { //find the first matching post/status by a fan page admin
            $message = $val->message;
            echo $message;
            break; //stop looping on most recent status posted by page admin
        }
    }
```

I found this code when I searched on google. But I did it as they indicated in their post, but now it's not working ?

Comment: What result did you expect? What did you get? What I am saying is: we can not guess what your exact situation is. Please give us more information.

Comment: i need to get most resent 20 facebook post via graph api...can you help me ? but i need to do it without authentication token. is it possible?

Comment: please update the opening post. It will make everything more clear for people who are opening this question for the first time. The better you structure your question, the more answers it will get. If you spend some extra time, the answering people will spend some extra time as well.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13854293/facebook-feeds-without-authentication-token-not-working

Comment: i posted this question several time but didn't get any answer yet

Comment: If you don't get a response, doesn't mean you have to repost it. I think you should then put more effort in your question instead of reposting it.

Comment: You ought to use a more descriptive title, perhaps "Can you get Facebook Feed without token using the Facebook Graph?".

Also, please include the link to the post you found on google.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible. Check this out.

This request: https://graph.facebook.com/cocacola/feed

Returns this response:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "An access token is required to request this resource.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 104
   }
}
```

Facebook likely requests an access_token so that they can rate-limit this call. It doesn't need to be a user `access_token`, just at least an App Access level `access_token`. Read about the differences here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/login/access-tokens-and-types/